# Is it ok to have both a placholder and a title on an input tag?

Tags: input, hover, placeholder

Is is a common practice to do that ? Or should I put informations linked to this input next to it ?

For example: `<input type="text" title="You first, not your last name !" placeholder="Name"/>`

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xcGx9/

Comment: Why to you post a complete external link to display a single line of code?

Comment: @André So that you can see what it looks like. I think the end result is more important than the code here.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a common practice, but I think it's not that bad, because in the title, which appears as a tooltip, you give additional information for the user once he enters the field using mouse pointer.

However, I think a better choice would be giving a field a label and use placeholder for descriptive text, so that it looks like:

Name: [ You first, not your last name ]

This way:

- user won't loose the purpose of the field while being inside the field
- it will work on touch devices the same way
- it will not depend on using the mouse pointer

Comment: I think that's a good advice. Placeholder shouldn't substitute a proper <label>, it's a hint, a complement. Something like this, perhaps: http://jsfiddle.net/rhWGA/2/ Also, there's been some discussion about the title tag: http://blog.paciellogroup.com/2010/11/using-the-html-title-attribute/